# Why isnt my interface implementation not working?

Tags: java, oop, collections, interface, project

I have made a java project which takes in a string of numbers and goes through some motions in interface methods to produce a result. I tested this without the implementation of the interface and it worked perfectly and produced the correct result. Here are the files of NumberRangeSummarizerImpl (No interaction with interface file yet, works perfect)

```
import java.util.*;
//import numberrangesummarizer;

public class NumberRangeSummarizerImpl {

    public Collection<Integer> collect(String input) 
    {
        
        // Split the input string into individual number strings and parse them into integers
        String[] numberStrings = input.split(",");
        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String numberString : numberStrings) {
            try {
                int number = Integer.parseInt(numberString.trim());
                numbers.add(number);
                //numbers are added to an arraylist 
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                // Ignore any non-integer input values t7hfy6h6tg6 number int add the sorted list t
            }
        }
        return numbers;
    }

    
    public String summarizeCollection(Collection<Integer> input) {
        if (input == null || input.isEmpty()) {
            return "Input invalid.";
        }
        // Sort the input numbers ASC
        List<Integer> sortedNumbers = new ArrayList<>(input);
        Collections.sort(sortedNumbers);
        
        // compile output string
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int startNumber = sortedNumbers.get(0);
        int lastNumber = startNumber;
        sb.append(startNumber);
        for (int i = 1; i < sortedNumbers.size(); i++) {
            int number = sortedNumbers.get(i);
            if (number == lastNumber + 1) {
                // The current number is sequential to the previous number
                lastNumber = number;
            } else {
                // The current number is not sequential to the previous number
                if (lastNumber > startNumber) {
                    // Output a range of numbers instead of just the lastNumber
                    sb.append("-").append(lastNumber);
                }
                sb.append(", ").append(number);
                startNumber = number;
                lastNumber = number;
            }
        }
        // Handle the last range of numbers, if there was one
        if (lastNumber > startNumber) {
            sb.append("-").append(lastNumber);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

App.java (Where main is)

```
import java.util.*;
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        NumberRangeSummarizerImpl summarizer = new NumberRangeSummarizerImpl();
        //Collection<Integer> inputNumbers = summarizer.collect("1,3,6,7,8,12,13,14,15,21,22,23,24,31");
        Collection<Integer> inputNumbers = summarizer.collect("1,1,3,6,7,8,12,13,14,15,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,31");
        String outputString = summarizer.summarizeCollection(inputNumbers);
        System.out.println(outputString);
    }
}
```

Now I have made an interface java file in the same folder (src)

```
package numberrangesummarizer;

import java.util.Collection;
public interface NumberRangeSummarizer {

    //collect the input
    Collection<Integer> collect(String input);

    //get the summarized string
    String summarizeCollection(Collection<Integer> input);

}
```

Now I need to use the interface by implementing it in NumberRangeSummarizerImpl

```
import java.util.*;
import numberrangesummarizer;

public class NumberRangeSummarizerImpl implements NumberRangeSummarizer {

    public Collection<Integer> collect(String input) 
    {
        
        // Split the input string into individual number strings and parse them into integers
        String[] numberStrings = input.split(",");
        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String numberString : numberStrings) {
            try {
                int number = Integer.parseInt(numberString.trim());
                numbers.add(number);
                //numbers are added to an arraylist 
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                // Ignore any non-integer input values t7hfy6h6tg6 number int add the sorted list t
            }
        }
        return numbers;
    }

    
    public String summarizeCollection(Collection<Integer> input) {
        if (input == null || input.isEmpty()) {
            return "Input invalid.";
        }
        // Sort the input numbers ASC
        List<Integer> sortedNumbers = new ArrayList<>(input);
        Collections.sort(sortedNumbers);
        
        // compile output string
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int startNumber = sortedNumbers.get(0);
        int lastNumber = startNumber;
        sb.append(startNumber);
        for (int i = 1; i < sortedNumbers.size(); i++) {
            int number = sortedNumbers.get(i);
            if (number == lastNumber + 1) {
                // The current number is sequential to the previous number
                lastNumber = number;
            } else {
                // The current number is not sequential to the previous number
                if (lastNumber > startNumber) {
                    // Output a range of numbers instead of just the lastNumber
                    sb.append("-").append(lastNumber);
                }
                sb.append(", ").append(number);
                startNumber = number;
                lastNumber = number;
            }
        }
        // Handle the last range of numbers, if there was one
        if (lastNumber > startNumber) {
            sb.append("-").append(lastNumber);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Its calling the package, the interface is in the same folder as Impl and yet **it throws an error where it cannot resolve NumberRangeSummarizer**

I dont understand why? Why is it failing to work?

Comment: this: import numberrangesummarizer; looks very dodgy. That 's the name of a package. You import classes, not packages, or you add .* at the end of it, indicating you import all the classes in that package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to rebuild your problem, where all three files exist in the src folder and it worked without the `import numberrangesummarizer;`.

Have you tried removing this statement?

Generally speaking its a [bad practice to have files not in a named package](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-1220)

Comment: Removing the import statement throws an error on the "public class NumberRangeSummarizerImpl implements NumberRangeSummarizer {"

NumberRangeSummarizer cannot be resolved to a typeJava(16777218)

Might you have the files? I cant get mine to work

Comment: @MillsBills Have you tried to clean and rebuild the solution? Things get icky sometimes, when refactoring.

Comment: clean build worked, damn this world for these insignificant reality-checks

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your `import` statement is correct.  That's not correct syntax, it should be `import package.Type`, or `import package.*`.

Also, Assuming that `NumberRangeSummarizerImpl` is in the same package as the interface type then you don't need to use an import statement at all.

Comment: I removed the import statement because all the files are in the same package

and yet I get " NumberRangeSummarizer cannot be resolved to a typeJava(16777218)" error on implementing NumberRangerSummarizer